# Multi-site sharing content

Tags: nodes, multi-sites

Is it possible to share content/nodes in a drupal multisite environment.

For example:

Content type "Story"

- Site 1- Use this content
- Site 2- Don't use this content
- Site 3- Use this content

It seems the drupal multisite environment suggests using table prefixes for different sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what the [domain access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module is for.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what Domain Access is for, but it isn't a true multisite environment.  It is for multiple sites running from a single database sharing some content.  It works very well, though, but can be a little bit of a pain to retroactively fit to a site.

Comment: This is perfect for what I need

Comment: And what if i would have not one database. It seems to me domain module would not help. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [deploy module](http://drupal.org/project/deploy) to push content to specified sites

Comment: How well does this work?

Comment: I haven't used in a while. If I recall correctly it required a bit to set up, had some challenges when using login redirect modules, like login toboggan. But it worked as expected once it was setup. I cannot comment on the state of the d& version, but I do see there are over 600 sites currently using it, so it must be working. Sorry, I cannot provide you with more info.